# Getting a return value from a channel

Tags: mirth

I would like to start a mirth channel from another mirth channel, wait for it to complete, stop it and then start another. I have this code in the main channel started. My question is how to I get a response back from the other channel? I do have the following line in channel 'CH1' as the last line.

```
return "<data><value>1</value></data>";
```

Snipped from MAIN CHANNEL:

```
var channelName = 'CH1'
ChannelUtil.StartChannel(channelName)

while (getChannelState(channelName).toUpperCase() == "STARTED") {

}

function getChannelState(channelName){

    var channelStatus = ChannelUtil.getChannelState(channelName);

    if(channelStatus != null){
            return channelStatus.toString();
    }

    return "UNKNOWN";
}
```

Comment: At first, it seems to me that you may better design your channels sequence. For example, one channel drops result to a folder, where another channel takes results for processing. Second, have you tried using any of the maps (GlobalMap, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by creating a controller channel that would switch channels on and off.

The child channels would send status updates to the controller by using the route message command in a javascript transformer.

```
router.routeMessage('CONTROL CHANNEL', 'I am done');
```

I'm curious though as to what you're trying to do.

Would creating a separate destination as a channel writer and sending a message to the child channel work?